# How to delete an indicated line in txt file with usage of DELETE Function in Python

Tags: python

I am a student and have a task to create a contact book with usage of oop, functions, txt file , import os.
I just decided to create a book with usage of functions and txt file.
And ...I have faced with some problem of deleting the indicated line (record) in txt file. I have tried many variations of how to do it. Result: delete an all information in the file or just last line, or simply read file and thats all. All I need is to delete a record as per indicated input(word/name).
my tutor edvised me to use a del function :

```
if each_contact.name==name:
    del list_contacts[i]
```

but i have no idea how to use this function at all. What the logic should be?
my code is like:

```
def del_contact_name():
 ## It should delete the required line as per name if txt file  

    del_name=input('Enter first name for delete  this contact record:  ')
    del_name=del_name.title()
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        file_delete = f.readlines()

    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        for line in file_delete:
            if line != del_name:
                f.write(line)
                print("Your Required Contact Record is deleted:", end=" ")
                break
```

and this is just delete only last line if I write a 3 lines of records ( it works, but  i need another result). If I do an one record it will not delete but read the line.
The full work looks like this:

```
file_name = "phonebook.txt"
filerec = open(file_name, "a+")
filerec.close


def show_main_menu():
    ## General menu 
    print("\n   Phone Book     \n"+
          "    my task and projects         \n"+
          "=================================\n"+
          "Enter 1,2,3,4 or 5:\n"+
          " 1 To Display Contacts Records\n" +
          " 2 To Add a New Contact Record\n"+
          " 3 To Search Contacts\n"+
          " 4 To Delete Contacts\n"+
          " 5 To Quit\n=========================")
    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if choice == "1":
        filerec = open(file_name, "r+")
        file_contents = filerec.read()
        if len(file_contents) == 0:
            print("Phone Book is Empty")
        else:
            print (file_contents)
        filerec.close
        entry = input("Press Enter to continue ...")
        show_main_menu()
    elif choice == "2":
        enter_contact_record()
        entry = input("Press Enter to continue ...")
        show_main_menu()
    elif choice == "3":
        search_contact_record()
        entry = input("Press Enter to continue ...")
        show_main_menu()
    elif choice=='4':
        del_contact_name()
        entry=input("Press Enter to continue ...")
        show_main_menu()

    elif choice== "5":
        print("Thanks for using Phone Book Programm ")
    else:
        print("Wrong choice, Please Enter [1 to 5]\n")
        entry = input("Press Enter to continue ...")
        show_main_menu()
        
def search_contact_record():
    ##' This function is used to searches a specific contact record 
    search_name = input("Enter First name for Searching contact record: ")

    search_name = search_name.title()
    filerec = open(file_name, "r+")
    file_contents = filerec.readlines()
     
    found = False   
    for line in file_contents:
        if search_name in line:
            print("Your Searched Contact Record is:", end=" ")
            print (line)
            found=True
            break
    if  found == False:
        print("There's no contact Record in Phone Book with name = " + search_name )

def enter_contact_record():
    ##  It  collects contact info firstname, last name, notes and phone
   
    first = input('Enter First Name: ')
    first = first.title()
    last = input('Enter Last Name: ')
    last = last.title()
    phone = input('Enter Phone number: ')
    notes = input('Enter notes: ')
    contact = ("[" + first + " " + last + ", " + phone + ", " + notes +  "]\n")
    filerec = open(file_name, "a")
    filerec.write(contact)
    print( "This contact\n " + contact + "has been added successfully!")


def del_contact_name():
    ## It should delete the required line as per name in txt file  

    del_name=input('Enter first name for delete  this contact record:  ')
    del_name=del_name.title()
    with open(file_name, "r") as f:
        file_delete = f.readlines()

    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        for line in file_delete:
            if line != del_name:
                f.write(line)
                print("Your Required Contact Record is deleted:", end=" ")
                break
 show_main_menu()
```

Comment: In your second loop, move the `print` statement to the left margin so it's not part of the loop, and remove the `break`.  You want to process EVERY line in the file.

Comment: Do not call `show_main_menu()` recursively.  Make it an infinite loop (`while True:`),  delete all the recursive calls, and in the `choice=='5'` case, add a `break`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    file_name = "phonebook.txt"  

def show_main_menu():
    ## General menu 
    print("\n   Phone Book     \n"+
          "    my task and projects         \n"+
          "=================================\n"+
          "Enter 1,2,3,4 or 5:\n"+
          " 1 To Display Contacts Records\n" +
          " 2 To Add a New Contact Record\n"+
          " 3 To Search Contacts\n"+
          " 4 To Delete Contacts\n"+
          " 5 To Quit\n=========================")
    choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
    if choice == "1":
        show_file()
        entry = input("Press Enter to continue ...")
        show_main_menu()
    elif choice == "2":
        add_file()
        entry = input("Press Enter to continue ...")
        show_main_menu()
    elif choice == "3":
        search_file()
        entry = input("Press Enter to continue ...")
        show_main_menu()
    elif choice=='4':
        dell_file()
        entry=input("Press Enter to continue ...")
        show_main_menu()
    elif choice== "5":
        print("Thanks for using Phone Book Programm ")
    else:
        print("Wrong choice, Please Enter [1 to 5]\n")
        entry = input("Press Enter to continue ...")
        show_main_menu()
  
def initials():
    first = input('Enter First Name: ')
    first = first.title()
    last = input('Enter Last Name: ')
    last = last.title()
    phone = input('Enter Phone number: ')
    notes = input('Enter notes: ')
    contact = ("[" + first + " " + last + ", " + phone + ", " + notes +  "]\n")
    return contact

def show_file():
    #show file
    filerec = open(file_name, "r+")
    file_contents = filerec.read()
    if len(file_contents) == 0:
        print("Phone Book is Empty")
    else:
        print (file_contents)
    filerec.close()

def add_file():
    #add text to a file
    with open(file_name, 'a') as f:
        f.write(initials())
    f.close()

def search_file():
    ##' This function is used to searches a specific contact record 
    search_name = input("Enter First name for Searching contact record: ")
    # If you enter not a name, but a sign that is in the record, then he will find it
    search_name = search_name.title()
    filerec = open(file_name, "r+")
    file_contents = filerec.readlines()
    found = True
    for line in file_contents:
        if search_name in line:
            print("Your Searched Contact Record is:", end=' ')
            print (line)
            found=False
            break  
    if found:
        print("There's no contact Record in Phone Book with name = " + search_name )
    filerec.close()

def dell_file():
    ## It should delete the required line as per name in txt file  
    del_name=input('Enter first name for delete  this contact record:  ')
    del_name=del_name.title()
    count_str = 0 
    no_string = True
    with open(file_name, "r+") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for i in lines:   
            count_str +=1       
            if del_name in i:
                no_string = False
                del lines[count_str-1]   
                break
    if no_string:
        print('No line')
    with open(file_name, "w") as file:
        file.writelines(lines)                
    file.close()

show_main_menu()
```

Now the deletion is working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).